# How to implement user-friendly paths in PHP without creating a file or directory for each page?

Tags: php, apache, handler

*NOTE: My terminology may not be entirely correct. I believe StackExchange does something like what I am asking, in case this can make things clearer.*

Using **PHP on Apache**, I would like to handle URLs such as:

```
http://www.site.com/info/<brand>/<model>/<page>
```

For example with `<brand> = toyota, <model> = camry, <page> = 'safety'`

And have all the URLs starting with 'info' (let's say) be handled by **a
single PHP file like 'info.php' without the URL in the location bar changing**.

In other words, someone navigates to:

```
http://www.site.com/info/toyota/camry/safety
```

But the code to handle this is in `info.php` but the URL in the browser stays
as is. I do not want to have to create all the /toyota/camera/safety directory
structure (there would be 1000s).

My guess is that info.php would get the path components as parameters in
order to know what content to serve. So the internal invocation invisible
to the user would be:

```
info.php?brand=toyota&model=camera&page=safety
```

Seems like the question here are doing something similar since they get URLs like:

```
http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/13978/how-to-implement-user-friendly-paths-in-php-without-creating-a-file-or-directory
```

and I presume the path there is not actually created on the server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you're using Apache, you want [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html), which is usually available by default.  mod_rewrite lets you *rewrite* requests as they come in.  It can make sub-requests, change the current request, or even redirect the user somewhere else.  It's an exceptionally powerful tool with a syntax that can be kind of obtuse at times.

You'll want to [set up `RewriteRule`s](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule).  `RewriteRule`s use the PCRE regular expression library, so if you've used regexes in Perl or the `preg` family of functions in PHP, you should be pretty familiar with the syntax.

There are two common patterns when making pretty URLs with mod_rewrite and PHP.  In the first, you'll pick a "mount point" under which all the pretty URLs will live, and instead invoke a PHP script that is given the rest of the path after the mount point.  For example, a call to `/info/toyota/camry/saftey` could be rewritten to `/info.php/toyota/camry/saftey`.

The PHP script would then access `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']`, which would contain `/toyota/camry/saftey`, and process that value as it needs to.  Yes, this will totally work.  Try it out yourself with a [phpinfo](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) script.  You'll find the bits after the file extension inside `PATH_INFO`.

Here's an untested but probably working example:

```
# ask mod_rewrite to turn itself on
    RewriteEngine On
# If the request is not for an actual file, then...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# ... capture the part of the path after /info/ and replace it 
# with a call to the PHP script.  In the regex, .+ means "Any 
# character, one or more times"
    RewriteRule ^/info/(.+)$ /info.php/$1
```

The second pattern is to set up a rewrite rule to actually extract parts of the path and turn it into a plain old regular query string.  This would be best if you have an existing script and don't want to make changes to it.  It can also be more complex, as you'd need to write one rule per set of candidate URLs.

Here's another untested but probably working example.

```
# /info/foo => info.php?brand=foo
# [^/]+ means "Any character that is not a /, one or more times
    RewriteRule ^/info/([^/]+)$ /info.php?brand=$1
# /info/foo/bar => info.php?brand=foo&model=bar
    RewriteRule ^/info/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /info.php?brand=$1&model=$2
# /info/foo/bar/baz => info.php?brand=foo&model=bar&page=baz
    RewriteRule ^/info/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /info.php?brand=$1&model=$2&page=$3
```

This is just a tip of the mod_rewrite iceburg.  There are [lots and lots and lots](http://www.google.com/search?q=mod_rewrite+php+pretty+urls) of tutorials and guides out there that can help you along.

Comment: Well, I've used mod_rewrite before but it always changes the user-visible URL (like a redirect). Is it a config option so that the user-entered URL stays fixed?

Comment: The first example seems to also catch mistypes URLs. Is that true? Wouldn't this create confusing 404s? I will try the second soon. Thanks for your help!

Comment: mod_rewrite will send a redirect (thus causing the user to make a new request, changing the URL) if you ask it to, using the [R flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_r).  If you omit the flag, it won't throw a redirect.  Both examples have the potential to accept input that would be invalid when processed by PHP.  You can simply have your script send a 404 page back, if the request would call for such a response.

Comment: The second example is screwing up paths and cant resources anymore. It seems like the path includes the bogus levels rather than the path of info.php (which is in the root). How can I avoid this?

Comment: As I noted, I didn't actually test any of these rewrites.  I actually only use the first form in production, and let my PHP code sort out the rest.  I *think* that [adding the L flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l) to each of those `RewriteRule`s should do the trick.

Comment: Still does not work. It seems like the fake path (/toyota/camry) is mistaken for a real path since I can no longer access the resources relative to info.php but I can access resources using ../ or ../../ or ../../../ depending on the path. The thing is the files are used in lots of places and they can't include resources with both the real path and relative all potential combinations of fake paths.

Comment: So, are you saying that you have an `/info/toyota/camry` directory or file already?  That does greatly complicate things.  I'm sure it can still be done, and I'm sure that mod_rewrite is still the right tool for the job, but I only really know the basics as I've never needed more.

Comment: No. Let me clarify with the simplest example I can think of. All my files, including info.php include resources using a relative path and that works when a user navigates to info.php?brand=toyota but when the user navigates to info/toyota (handled by info.php?brand=toyota) the ALL resources (CSS, IMG) are no longer found. If I change the path to the CSS and images by adding a ../ (parent dir) in front then it works for the latter but not the former... and of course there are lots of potential depths (/brand/mode, /brand/model/info, etc).

Comment: Solution: don't *do* that!  Absolute paths are best, even if they can be more verbose.

Comment: So I take it there is no work-around and that the fake part of the path always causes internal confusion somewhere? Got to insist since I have over 10000 (yes, ten thousand) files to go through for this one site otherwise :(

Comment: Oh holy *yikes*. I think you're going to need to do a mass search and replace. If not for the depth of your directory structure, I could recommend just adding *more* rewrite rules to catch the missing directories and serve up the right files, but that's going to utterly *slaughter* caching of those resources.

Comment: Guess this is the right answer then. Thank you for everything!

Comment: This was madness but I finally changed over 384000 links (using half a dozen regexps) and the htaccess inspired from your example 2 worked. Glad the weekend is here now :)